# Using CMake to create a Visual Studio Remote Linux build project

Tags: visual-studio, cmake, embedded-linux, remote-debugging

I want to create a Visual Studio (2019) solution/project on Windows to remote build and debug on an embedded linux target which runs Ubuntu (to make it easier, let's pretend it's a Raspberry Pi) connected by SSH.

I managed to create one using the Visual Studio project creator. But the next step is to use CMake to create the solution/project from the source files.

I started making a simple CMake script:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0)

project(testproject)

file(GLOB SOURCE "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/source/*.cpp")
file(GLOB HEADERS "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include/*.h")


include_directories("${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include") 
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${SOURCE} ${HEADERS})
```

But this only creates a regular windows console application project. What commands or CMake-Config do I have to add, to create the remote building/debugging project?

Answer (score 0):

Do you know what is a cross compilation ? and a cross toolchain ?

You should take a look at the CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE
https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-toolchains.7.html#cross-compiling-for-linux